# Maximizing the probability based on binomial distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, optimization, maxima-minima

What values of $P_{Y}$ and $P_{X}$ maximizes $P(Z=1)$ where the random variable $Z$ is given by,
$$
Z=Y+X
$$
where $X \sim$ Binomial $\left(n_{1}, P_{X}\right)$ and $Y \sim$ Binomial $\left(n_{2}, P_{Y}\right)$ ?

My attempt:

I understand that the problem is same as

> $\operatorname{argmax}_{P_{Y},P_{X}  }  n_{1}P_{X}(1-P_{X})^{n_{1}-1}(1-P_{Y})^{n_{2}}+ n_{2}P_{Y}(1-P_{Y})^{n_{2}-1}(1-P_{X})^{n_{1}}$

Now, I will take the derivative w.r.t $P_{X}$ $ \&$ $P_{Y}$ and equate to zero.

This simplifies to,

> $ -n_{1}P_{X} -(n_{2}+1)P_{Y}+ (n_{1} +n_{2})P_{X}P_{Y}+1=0$ and
>   $ -n_{2}P_{Y} -(n_{1}+1)P_{X}+ (n_{1} +n_{2})P_{X}P_{Y}+1=0$

which implies $P_{X}=P_{Y}$.

This seems wrong because intuitively $P_{X}$ $\&$ $P_{Y}$ should also depend on $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$
.

Could someone help me solve this confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts / not a full answer.

Perhaps the answer $P_X = P_Y = {1 \over n_1 + n_2}$ is not a maximum?  It can't be a minimum over all $(P_X, P_Y) \in [0,1]^2$, obviously, but it might be a saddle point.

That answer is basically saying we're best off if we treat both pools of $n_1$ and $n_2$ flips the same, and combine them into a single $Binomial(n_1 + n_2, {1 \over n_1 + n_2})$.  Well, whatever that value of $P(Z=1)$ turns out to be, I'm *guessing* the following proposed solution has higher $P(Z=1)$:

- Without loss of generality assume $1\le n_1 \le n_2$.  Then play $Bin(n_1, {1 \over n_1})$ and $Bin(n_2, 0)$.

I have not gone through the trouble of evaluating these, but it seems intuitively obvious my proposal would have a higher $P(Z=1)$, because it seems obvious that $f_k = P(Binomial(k, {1\over k}) = 1)$ is strictly decreasing in $k$.

In particular for the boundary case of $n_1 = 1$, my proposal would give $P(Z=1)=1$.

I am not sure whether my proposal is optimal.  Just saying I'm guessing it beats the other solution.

Also, if my proposal turns out to be optimal, then you cannot find it using derivatives *alone* because it happens at the boundary of $(P_X, P_Y) \in [0,1]^2$.  However, you have found the only solution in the interior which is a maximum / minimum / saddlepoint, so all you gotta do is compare it to all solutions at the boundaries (i.e. with at least one of $P_X$ or $P_Y$ being $0$ or $1$) and then you can find the global maximum within $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. Your last point is correct: you just need to compare the interior critical point $P_X=P_Y=(n_1+n_2)^{-1}$ with points on the boundary. Choosing $P_X=1$ or $P_Y=1$ will not be helpful except in trivial cases. You can show that $P(\text{Binom}(n, 1/n) = 1) = (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n-1}$ is strictly decreasing in $n$, so your solution of $(1/n_1, 0)$ is better than $(0, 1/n_2)$ and $(1/(n_1+n_2), 1/(n_1+n_2))$ in the case $n_1 < n_2$.

Comment: @angryavian If I am required to have a non zero probability for Px and Py , what happens?

Comment: @JyotishRobin Then there is no maximizer, since (in the case $n_1 < n_2$) you can take $P_X = 1/n_1$ and $P_Y \to 0$ to increase the probability arbitrarily close to the maximum value $(1-n_1^{-1})^{n_1 - 1}$.

Comment: Why would you be required to have non-zero $P_X, P_Y$ anyway?  That's like saying maximize $7x + 4$ in the _open_ interval $(0,1)$.  You know you want $x=1$ but it's artificially excluded because of the open interval.  :)

Comment: @antkam That's true. I understand.  I have a follow-up question too. Will it be right to say that the same results hold true even for Z = X1+ X2+ X3+X4....+ Xn. Where Xi~ bin(ni,pi).

Comment: @JyotishRobin - my gut feel is Yes the result generalizes, but I haven't gone through a proof.  You still have to find the interior critical points, but hopefully, the $n$ variables case will still have only one interior critical point, where all $P_i = 1/(\sum_j n_j)$.  Then you compare it to the boundary and as angryavian helpfully pointed out, any $P_i=1$ is useless except in trivial cases, so you only have to consider cases where some $P_i = 0$.  But $P_i = 0$ means one fewer Binomial r.v. (i.e. as if $X_i$ didn't exist) so you can do induction on $n$.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking a bit further. I note that all the three points of interest 1/n1, 1/n1+n2, 1/n2 were trying to keep the E(Z)=1 because the maximum of binomial happens at the expected value assuming it is an integer.

Now I have an extension of the problem:
Say, once I get z=1, I remove that item from the population. ie, n1 becomes n1-1. Then I again repeat my experiment. 

So, I am guessing ,now I should choose Px_new =1/(n1-1).

And after several iterations, once (n1)->(n1-1)->.. (n2-1), I should alternately start sampling from Y and X . Does it make sense?

Comment: Or actually, I could combine the 2 sets , once  n1 reduces to n2.